# mono-project on dreamboxn dm7080 HD

Tags: linux, silverlight, mono, mips

I did not find a way to install mono-project for my dream box.
It would be cool, to watch official TV in Switzerland over my brand new DM7080 and it's browser.

What I found on the net is:

[www.mono-project.com](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/mips/)

Unfortunately, I did not find a document how to install it.

I tried this:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF

echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list

apt-get install mono-revel
```

which results in the following error:

```
root@dm7080:~# apt-get install mono-devel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    mono-devel : Depends: mono-runtime (>= 2.10.1) but it is not installable
          Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.32.3) but it is not installable
          Depends: libmono-cecil-private-cil (>= 3.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-cecil-private-cil (< 3.12.1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-codecontracts4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-compilerservices-symbolwriter4.0-cil (>= 3.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-corlib2.0-cil (>= 3.2.8) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-corlib4.5-cil (>= 3.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-peapi2.0a-cil (>= 3.2.8) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-peapi4.0a-cil (>= 3.2.8) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-relaxng4.0-cil (>= 2.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-security2.0-cil (>= 3.0.6) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-security4.0-cil (>= 3.0.6) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-system-componentmodel-composition4.0-cil (>= 3.0.6) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-system-componentmodel-dataannotations4.0-cil (>= 3.2.3) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-system-configuration-install4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-system-core4.0-cil (>= 3.2.8) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-system-data-linq4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-system-data2.0-cil (>= 3.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-system-data4.0-cil (>= 3.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-system-numerics4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-system-runtime-serialization4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-system-runtime4.0-cil (>= 2.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-system-security4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil (>= 3.2.3) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-system-web2.0-cil (>= 2.10.3) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-system-xml-linq4.0-cil (>= 3.0.6) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-system-xml4.0-cil (>= 3.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-system2.0-cil (>= 3.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-system4.0-cil (>= 3.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono2.0-cil (>= 3.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: mono-mcs (= 3.12.0-0xamarin2) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: mono-gac (= 3.12.0-0xamarin2) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: mono-xbuild (= 3.12.0-0xamarin2) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-cil-dev (= 3.12.0-0xamarin2) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmono-2.0-dev (>= 3.12.0-0xamarin2) but it is not installable
          Depends: libmono-2.0-dev (< 3.12.0-0xamarin2.1~) but it is not installable
          Depends: pkg-config but it is not installable
          Recommends: mono-csharp-shell but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Looks like you are downloading the x86 compiled libraries. You should try cross-compiling into MIPS using the sources.

Comment: Hi markgz, thanks for your reply, do you mean I should checkout this repository: https://github.com/mono/monodevelop, than make & make install?

Comment: Yes. You will need to either build on a MIPS box, or cross-compile for MIPS.